# Apply Undo Redo on elements that can dragable (drag and drop)

Tags: javascript, svg, undo-redo

I want to implement functionality on the svgElements that can be dragged with javascript how could I do this...

I have implemented this with mouse up

When mouse up occurs, I save the x and y position, object id, object type (circle, rect, etc.)

**Can any one tell...is this good way to implement?**

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how to implement undo/redo functionality in general, it's fairly simple: you have an array of actions and a counter.  You push new elements onto the array when actions occur and step backwards when people hit undo.

Very basic implementation:

```
var history = {
    stack   : [],
    counter : -1,
    add     : function(item){
        this.stack[++this.counter] = item;
        this.doSomethingWith(item);

        // delete anything forward of the counter
        this.stack.splice(this.counter+1);
    },
    undo : function(){
        this.doSomethingWith(this.stack[--this.counter]);
    },
    redo : function(){
        this.doSomethingWith(this.stack[++this.counter]);
    },
    doSomethingWith : function(item){
        // show item
    }
};
```

Note that there should be basic error checking to see that counter doesn't go beyond bounds and that you may want to pass 'undo' info into `doSomethingWith` in the case of an undo, but all that is app specific.

Answer (score 1):

cwolves describes a good structure for the undo/redo functionality.

You are correct, that during mouse-up, you'll want to store the history, but you'll also want to store the original location of the object(s) being manipulated during mouse-down so you'll have have it when you undo the move.

If you end up taking it a step further, and allowing scaling, then you'll want to store the complete original transform e.g. "translate(10,10) scale(1.2,1.2) rotate(90)", for history, but also so that you'll have a baseline to apply the drag-scaling action to.

Comment: thanks josh pearce,onmousedown if i save the location it will save two time (because its save on mouseup also) i have completed almost...but the problem is there its save last location 2 time.. when i press undo button 2 time  then object undo(going its last position)

Answer (score 1):

I found a better structure without counter, index shift or limit handling problems.
Simply 2 stack for "done" and "reverted" action that are balancing.

```
var history = function() {
    this.done = this.reverted = [];
    var self = this;

    this.add = function(item) {
        self.done.push(item);

        // delete anything forward
        self.reverted = [];
    };

    this.undo = function() {
        var item = self.done.pop();

        if (item) {
            self.reverted.push(item);
        }

        return item;
    };

    this.redo = function() {
        var item = self.reverted.pop();

        if (item) {
            self.done.push(item);
        }

        return item;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the above codes.
I attempted to use those and found out that I had to hit undo twice initially before it started going down the array.

So say I have done[0] done[1] done[2].
done[2] was just saved into the array. If I hit undo, it returns that. You dont want that. It is replacing what is already there. But hitting undo again, THEN you get your previous code.

Mine, as I have a drag and drop editor with different modes of edits. Drag and Drop Elements. Edit Elements HTML/Pictures. Sorting elements.

$("#neoContentContainer") contains all editor html.
And you can call editor_add on clicks, mousedowns ect... seeing it is a function you can easily call.

```
function editor_add(){
    undo.push($("#neoContentContainer").html());
    update_buttons();
}
function editor_undo(){
    var item = undo.pop();
    // prevent undo/redo from undoing to the same HTML currently shown. 
    if(item == $("#neoContentContainer").html()){
        redo.push(item);
        item = undo.pop();
    }
    if(item){
        redo.push(item);
        $("#neoContentContainer").html(item);
    }
    update_buttons();
}
function editor_redo(){
    var item = redo.pop();
    if(item == $("#neoContentContainer").html()){
        undo.push(item);
        item = redo.pop();
    }
    if(item){
        undo.push(item);
        $("#neoContentContainer").html(item);
    }
    update_buttons();
}
function update_buttons(){
    if(undo.length == 0){
        $('button[data-id="undo"]').attr('disabled',true);
    } else {
        $('button[data-id="undo"]').attr('disabled',false);
    }

    if(redo.length == 0){
        $('button[data-id="redo"]').attr('disabled',true);
    } else {
        $('button[data-id="redo"]').attr('disabled',false);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s1L6vv5y/

Not perfect, but get the jist of it. (Still wondering when we can get ONE LINE LINE BREAKS!!!! DEVS AT STACKOVERFLOW!! :)

So when my page loads, I run: editor_add();
Because when they do something, it needs to undo to something!

Now every time they drop something, sort things I run editor_add(); Took me all day, now realizing how simple it was this works very well for me.

So with this one, which is good....

```
var history = function() {
    this.done = this.reverted = [];
    var self = this;

    this.add = function(item) {
        self.done.push(item);
    };

    this.undo = function() {
        if(done.length >= 3){
            var undo_item = self.done.pop();
            self.reverted.push(undo_item);
        }

        var item = self.done.pop(); 
        if (item) {
            self.reverted.push(item);
        }

        return item;
    };

    this.redo = function() {
        if(reverted.length >= 3){
            var revert_item = self.reverted.pop();
            self.done.push(revert_item);
        }
        var item = self.reverted.pop();
        if (item) {
            self.done.push(item);
        }

        return item;
    };
};
```

You do not want to clear the redos until you ran through the array.

(Guess logging in before editing helps!)