# Javascript history of actions done by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a question that have a lot of possible answers, but I'm looking the best way to perform it.

I need a history of actions/movements done by the user. Imagining that I have a workspace, where the user can drag, rotate, resize and delete divs, something like that:

```
<div class="myWorkSpace">
     <div id="GUID1" style="left: 30px; top: 10px;"></div>
     <div id="GUID2" style="left: 20px; top: 20px;"></div>
     <div id="GUID3" style="left: 10px; top: 30px;"></div>
</div>
```

I put [here](http://jsfiddle.net/95Rb9/) a Fiddle with more real code.

The user drag one div and change the left and top position of the div. If the user press a button named "Undo", the div comes back to the original position.

I need to do a history of movements, but I have a lot of possibilities in my mind, and I don't know if exist some plugin or some example or a correct way to do that.

I think I can use an array of movement, and store there the changes, but I think it's very hard-code. If you see my real code in the Fiddle, you will see that I have a lot of code and properties for each div, and if the user for example, press the button delete div and after undo, I would need to restore all the properties of the deleted div (including the guid id).

Any suggestion? Thanks!!

Comment: What code ? There are only CSS and HTML in your Fiddle, what did you try ? Do you except us to do all the work ?

Comment: @singe31 I don't need code, just concepts!! I don't need that anybody do my work...

Answer (score 1):

Maby this is an idea?

Quote from [This Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617447/apply-undo-redo-on-elements-that-can-dragable-drag-and-drop)

```
var history = {
stack   : [],
counter : -1,
add     : function(item){
    this.stack[++this.counter] = item;
    this.doSomethingWith(item);

    // delete anything forward of the counter
    this.stack.splice(this.counter+1);
},
undo : function(){
    this.doSomethingWith(this.stack[--this.counter]);
},
redo : function(){
    this.doSomethingWith(this.stack[++this.counter]);
},
doSomethingWith : function(item){
    // show item
}};
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrius, and the tittle of the post will be very useful for looking more ideas!! ;)