# Functionality undo and redo with draggable and resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, undo-redo

After write [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032040/javascript-history-of-actions-done-by-user), I have been working in a example to develope two history buttons (undo and redo) with some divs which can be resized or draggable.

More or less, it's working, but I have a problem because I don't know how to do that the buttons undo or redo don't need  to be pressed two times by the user.

I am storing the star event of drag and resize for undo, and I'm storing the stop event of drag and resize for the redo.

I have some ideas in mind for solve the problem, but I don't like, one of them if check if the div has the same style, make another redo or undo.

Can anybody explain me how can I do that in a correct way? [Here you have a Fiddle with all the funcionality](http://jsfiddle.net/chemitaxis/5wmCg/4/)

**HTML**

Undo
        Redo

```
<div class="workspace">

    <div class="editable" id="panel1" style="width:50px; height:50px; left: 10px; top:10px; background-color: #3498db;"></div>
    <div class="editable" id="panel2" style="width:50px; height:50px; left: 70px; top:10px; background-color: #f1c40f"></div>
    <div class="editable" id="panel3" style="width:50px; height:50px; left: 130px; top:10px; background-color: #16a085;"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.editable
{
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
}

.workspace
{
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.buttonsMenu
{
    position:absolute;
    padding:20px;
    height: 30px;

}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
//History Object
var historyApp = {
    stackStyle   : [],
    stackId   : [],
    counter : -1,
    add     : function(style, id){

        ++this.counter;
        this.stackStyle[this.counter] = style;
        this.stackId[this.counter] = id;
        this.doSomethingWith(style, id);

        // delete anything forward of the counter
        this.stackStyle.splice(this.counter+1);
    },
    undo : function(){
        --this.counter;
        this.doSomethingWith(this.stackStyle[this.counter],this.stackId[this.counter]);        
    },
    redo : function(){
        ++this.counter;
        this.doSomethingWith(this.stackStyle[this.counter],this.stackId[this.counter]);

    },
    doSomethingWith : function(style, id){

        //Check if make buttons undo/redo disabled or enabled
        if(this.counter <= -1)
        {
            $('#undo').addClass('disabled');            
            $('#redo').removeClass('disabled'); 
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#undo').removeClass('disabled');            
        }


        if(this.counter == this.stackStyle.length)
        {
            $('#redo').addClass('disabled');
            $('#undo').removeClass('disabled');           
            return;
        }        
        else
        {
            $('#redo').removeClass('disabled');            
        }


        console.log(style + ' - ' + id);
        //Apply history style
        $('#' + id).attr('style', style);     

        console.log(this.counter + ' - ' + this.stackStyle.length);

    }
};


$(document).ready(function (e) {

    //make class .editable draggable
    $('.editable').draggable(
    {
        stop: stopHandlerDrag,
        start: startHandlerDrag

    });

    //make class .editable resizable    
    $('.editable').resizable(
    {
        stop: stopHandlerResize,
        start: startHandlerResize

    });

});

//Stop Handler Drag
function stopHandlerDrag(event, ui)
{
    var style = $(ui.helper).attr('style');
    var id = $(ui.helper).attr('id');
    historyApp.add(style, id);

}    

//Star Handler Drag
function startHandlerDrag(event, ui)
{
    var style = $(ui.helper).attr('style');
    var id = $(ui.helper).attr('id');
    historyApp.add(style, id);
}

//Stop Handler Resize
function stopHandlerResize(event, ui)
{
    var style = $(ui.helper).attr('style');
    var id = $(ui.helper).attr('id');
    historyApp.add(style, id);
}

//Star Handler Resize
function startHandlerResize(event, ui)
{
    var style = $(ui.helper).attr('style');
    var id = $(ui.helper).attr('id'); 
    historyApp.add(style, id);
}

//Click Events For Redo and Undo
$(document).on('click', '#redo', function () {
    historyApp.redo();
});

$(document).on('click', '#undo', function () {
    historyApp.undo();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your main issue is that you call `history.add()` twice per event (`start` + `stop`).

One solution could be to bind the `start` event to trigger only once per ui

```
function startHandlerDrag(event, ui)
{
    console.log('start drag');
    var style = $(ui.helper).attr('style');
    var id = $(ui.helper).attr('id');
    historyApp.add(style, id);

    //Dettach all events
    $('#'+id).draggable("option", "revert", false);
    $('#'+id).resizable("destroy");
    //reassign stop events
    $('#'+id).draggable(
    {
        stop: stopHandlerDrag,
        start: ''    
    });
    $('#'+id).resizable(
    {
        stop: stopHandlerResize,
        start: '' 
    });

 }
```

do the same with `startHandlerResize`

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wmCg/8/)

Ps: there seems to be a bug in your `redo` function : I had some issues while I restarted from an "undone" position. But I let you look at this.