# How to store and retrieve later data() object from DOM element for undo/redo functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am implementing undo/redo in my js app (sticker designer with drawing/change color etc.). I'm using basic example https://stackoverflow.com/a/31149931/1802137

For simple storing it is something like this:

```
var undo = []; var redo = [];
function editor_add(){
   undo.push($("#parentDiv").html());
}
editor_add();
```

HTML:

```
<div id='parentDiv'>
 <span id='id-0'></span>
 <span id='id-1'></span>
 <span id='id-2'></span>
</div>
```

Then I retrieve it with:

```
function editor_undo(){
    var item_redo = undo.pop();
    redo.push(item_redo);
    var item = undo.pop();
    if(item){
       redo.push(item);
       $("#parentDiv").html(item);
    }
}
```

It works with reverting DOM elements, but of course it doesn't save data() from each element, just a whole html within parent.

I figured out I'd need to store all data() for each element in array together with html. So, I guess I could put html string in each data object, then retrieve it with the rest of data. Array should be:

```
undo = [{html0, data0},{html1, data1},{html2, data2}];
```

Or is there a better way to store selector html with data and then put it back?

Here's the example of two data() object stored in array (first one is undefined).

[image: Here's the example of two data() object stored in array (first one is undefined).]

Comment: Unsure what you mean by `it doesn't save data() from each element`.  Can you add something to the question showing this `data()` being populated?

Comment: @Archer, added in the bottom

Comment: Doesn't help at all I'm afraid.  Can you add something to the question showing this `data()` being populated?  Is it just a completely separate array, or are you somehow associating it with the DOM elements?

Comment: @altermind you can use window.localStorage object to save your changes even after postback. If you are not using postback then you can simply save in a javascript json object. I am not able to understand where you are getting stuck?

Comment: @Archer, i.e. there's a function to rotate element  `rotate: function(e, angle){
   deg = angle;
   if( typeof e != Object ) var o = jQuery(e);
   else var o = e;
   o.rotatable({angle: deg, 
    rotate: function(event, angle){
     var deg = parseInt(angle.r);
     if(deg < 0) deg = 360 + deg;
     o.data('rotate', deg);
    }
   });
  },` you can see there's `o.data('rotate', deg);` being populated

Comment: @vibs2006, so instead of saving data() object for each element I can save all together with window.localStorage? Store it and then retrieve it?

Comment: @altermind you can save all individual element data in a single json object, then do `JSON.stringify(yourJsonObject)` and save it to your localStorage object like `window.localStorage.setItem("MasterJsonObject",JSON.stringify(yourJsonObj));` and retrive it later `JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("MasterJsonObject"))` as JSON object. If you want working fiddle then create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net etc

Comment: @vibs2006, I think I got you. I'm trying to save it in javascript json object, but could use window.localStorage too

Comment: @vibs2006 can you copy it as an answer and I'll upvote/accept it?

Comment: ok sure @altermind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per question here we considering undo as the json object which will save all the data. Data should be saved something like

```
var undo = [{ html0: data0 }, { html1: data1 }, { html2: data2 }];
//Saving to LocalStorage. 
//Advantages are data is still available on postback / reload of page

function saveToLocalStorage() {
    window.localStorage.setItem("undo", JSON.stringify(undo));
}

function getFromLocalStorage() {
    undo = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("undo"));
}
```